# Raspberries drying

Tags: plant-health, raspberries, outdoor

I've received a couple of raspberry straws last year, planted them and they grew well.

March this year I've transplanted them to another location.

All the 6 plants started growing, however around May they started drying, one by one, starting from end of the row, always the next one.

I've now only three and one of them will die soon. Also only one of them has young stems, so I hope at least that will survive for next year.

As they've grown well I don't think I've done transplanting wrong. Also this year is wet, water shouldn't be a problem too (soil is sandy, so low chance for too much water). Neither I see diseases or insects, so no clue what happens.

[image]

Comment: What kind of raspberrys ? Blacks are very susceptible to anthracnose ; they seem to  "dry"

Comment: Mine are red. I've added a picture to the question.